# Minimal rails auth script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, rubygems

Someone got a tip for a minimal rails auth script or gem? It should include just the following points:

- authentication by email-address
- registration with email-address and password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into devise gem: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

It can do a lot more than that, but it is a very easy to use gem for such a purpose.

It handles the views and passwords resets too.

Comment: If the question is authentication the answer is devise.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, devise is great! If those are truly your requirements then I would suggest that too.  If, on the other hand, you are looking for the most minimal authentication system possible, I would encourage you to consider the omniauth gem: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

It will allow you to totally offload authentication to a third party (facebook, google, twitter, etc).  This is a great way to avoid writing any of that logic at all.